# using fit_params from pipeline sklearn for training

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using `XGBClassifier` from `xgboost` library in a `Pipeline` from sklearn but whenever i want to access one of the `**fit_params` in the way that the library says to do so https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit i got `keyerrors`

```
xgb_model = XGBClassifier(eval_metric='logloss', use_label_encoder=False)
pipeline = Pipeline([("preproc", preprocesser), ("classifier", xgb_model)])
pipeline.fit(
    X_train, y_train, train_model__eval_set=[(X_valid_transformed, y_valid)]
)
```

i got

```
Keyerror: 'train_model'
```

Comment: There may be other problems, but did you mean `... classifier__eval_set= ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`sklearn.pipeline` docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html#sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.fit):

```
...
**fit_paramsdict of string -> object
  Parameters passed to the fit method of each step,
  where each parameter name is prefixed such that
  parameter p for step s has key s__p
...
```

So, for your code, you need:

```py
                                                      |
                                                      |
                                                      v
                                                   ________
                                                  |        |
pipeline = Pipeline([("preproc", preprocesser), ("classifier", xgb_model)])
pipeline.fit(
    X_train, y_train, classifier__eval_set=[(X_valid_transformed, y_valid)]
)                     |________|
                          ^
                          |
                          |
```